# How to crop images with description file in opencv

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier, createsamples

I used imagemaker tool to select targets for positive library, and generated a description file, i want to know how i can get the images cropped with the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to put more effort in explaining your problem. - Do you possibly mean ImageClipper tools? ",i want to know how i can get the images cropped with the file?" - What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly mean the ImageClipper tool? If so, there is no implemented solution to save your cropped positives.